# Straightness measure for smooth 2-d plane curves of a given fixed length

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

Consider a smooth, 2-d plane curve of given fixed length $d$. Any straight line of length $d$, is also a curve of this type. What i am interested in is, How straight a curve of a fixed length, is? In terms of a mathematical measure. For example the straightness measure of a straight line of length $d$, is greater than the measure of any other smooth curve of length $d$. This measure intuitively, should be independent of the orientation or location of the curve in the plane. Basically shift invariant and rotation invariant.

Comment: Perhaps the integral of the curvature? This is smaller for "straighter" curves but if that matters you can just take $1/\kappa$ or similar.

Comment: Here I use measure as a general term, like temperature, height, etc. Not to be confused with measure as in measure theory.

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis : seems intuitive. Isn't there any name for integral of curvature, already in the literature? I would be surprised if there isn't.

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis : moreover the curvature can be of both positive and negative, and we don't want positive and negative curvatures cancelling each other!

Comment: Good point, you probably want to take $\int |\kappa|$ then.

Comment: I think "total unsigned curvature" would be the appropriate name for this quantity.

Comment: Basically the same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/473798/856

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis : I am not happy with this curvature thing, as just a small local twist to an otherwise very straight curve would cause this measure to be high for this curve, but we know the curve is almost straight.

Comment: @RahulNarain : oops so darn similar questions, that too in a span of eight hours, surprising. Wonder what do we do about it?

Comment: I guess you want ⎬ to be straighter than ⟌ even though the former turns 90 degrees and then back again but the latter only turns 90 degrees once?  Why not just integrate the distance from the curve to the line joining the endpoints?  I'll make this an answer...

Comment: @Dan Brumleve : i am not able to see the figures/equations in your comment. they just appear as boxes. could you re-post them, may be in an answer.

Comment: They are unicode characters with certain shapes, I will fix the answer to not use them.

Answer (score 1):

You want [image: dilly] to be straighter than [image: ell] even though the former turns 360 degrees and the latter only turns 90 degrees.  The average inverse curvature is not really what you want since a straight line and a line with a single sharp bend (L) are both "straight" in this sense.  Instead, why not use the inverse average distance (or average inverse distance) between the curve and the line joining its endpoints?

Comment: seems legitimate.

Comment: thx so is your q

Comment: Even simpler, just use the distance between the endpoints itself.  Curvier curves will have closer endpoints...  But then a very wiggly line that proceeds in one direction would have a small straightness, so I'm not sure if that is better or worse.

Comment: Do we have a precise justification for selecting the line that joins the end points. I mean why only end points?

Comment: @RajeshD: Why not the endpoints? A *straight* line is the shortest distance between two (end)points. So it would seem *one* measure of the straightness would seem to be to compare the length of the curve with the distance between the endpoints. (When asking a soft question, expect soft answers.)